# dmake installation issue on linux

Tags: makefile, dmake

I'm trying to build openssl 1.0.1h on linux, when I ran 'make' seems it looks for dmake and its not found on my system.

```
bash# make
making all in crypto...
/bin/sh: dmake: command not found
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

so I downloaded dmake 4.12 and tried to build it as well, but I encountered another strange issue.
I was manage to ran ./configure and it seems to be ok, but when running 'make' I'm getting:

```
dmake  all-recursive
**make: dmake: Command not found**
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

I'm trying to build and install dmake but 'make' command is using dmake in my env.
What is the solution here? how can I build it?

Comment: Look to see whether you have exported `MAKE=dmake` — probably with `env | grep '^MAKE='`.  This would account for the symptoms you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo $MAKE showed 'dmake'
some env script changed it from 'gmake' to 'dmake'
solution: export MAKE=gmake